# Removing active class on click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some filters on a project I'm working on that once clicked, it's given a class of `active`, which will then show a div inside the clicked list item called `info-pane`.

The filters are the 6 blue boxes. I am using the jQuery below to add and remove the active class, however the issue comes when I want to try and remove the active class by clicking the list item that has the active class state but it doesn't seem to work.

The code I'm trying;

```
$(".filters > ul > li").click(function() {
    $(".filters > ul > li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
$(".filters > ul > li.active").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Here's a link to the live project; http://client.n8geeks.com/

Comment: can you create a plnkr or fiddler reflecting your problem?

Comment: add necessary html also

Comment: I have added a link to the live code, I think it mgiht be easier to view that way? If you'd still prefer I can create a fiddle.

Comment: You should combine both click functions.

Comment: click events do not get magically bound to elements after the code has run. It is like walking into a room after a person already called your name. You are not ever going to hear them call your name unless they yell it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(".filters > ul > li").click(function() {
    $(".filters > ul > li").not($(this).toggleClass("active")).removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to make two events for that click. Here is example to do in one. But i can't see where your problem is. In your live project i can see that filters change after you click..?

```
$(".filters > ul > li").click(function() {
        $(".filters").find('li').removeClass('active');    
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Edit:

I don't know if i understood correctly, but i can see when you click on 'x' nothing happens.. so function that reset your filters.

**(non-tested)**

```
$(".close").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('ul > li').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });   
});
```